# MultiBinding - Specified Cast Is Not Valid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, casting, multibinding

The code below binds column widths: `Samp1.ActualWidth` and `Samp2.ActualWidth` to `StatName.Width`. See: [Bind DataGrid Column Width to Two Colums of Another DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762162/bind-datagrid-column-width-to-two-colums-of-another-datagrid)

However, the Designer reports the error `Specified cast is not valid.`, but in spite of the error, the code still compiles and executes as expected.

Even though it runs as expected, the "error" still bugs me.

**Question:** What is causing the error: `Specified cast is not valid.`?  What is being cast to what?  How can I fix it?  If a fix is not straightforward, how can I at least hide or ignore the error?

**Note:** The question [WPF MultiBinding VS designer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670802/wpf-multibinding-vs-designer-exception) is similar.  However, that code causes a runtime exception, while my code causes a build error and runs fine (without any exceptions thrown).

Xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<!--- ... -->
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Samp1" Binding="{Binding a}" Header="S1"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Samp2" Binding="{Binding b}" Header="S2"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Total" Binding="{Binding c}" Header="Tot" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <local:MyGenericRecord a="5000" b="2500" c="7500" />
    <local:MyGenericRecord a="1000" b="1500" c="2500" />
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StatName"  Binding="{Binding a}" Header="Stat">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Width >
                <!-- ####################################### -->
                <!-- Begin error: Specified cast is invalid. -->
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}">
                    <Binding Source="{x:Reference Samp1}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    <Binding Source="{x:Reference Samp2}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                </MultiBinding>
                <!-- End error -->
                <!-- ###################################### -->
            </DataGridTextColumn.Width>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StatValue" Binding="{Binding b}" Header="Val" Width="{Binding ElementName=Total, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <local:MyGenericRecord a="Min" b="2500" />
    <local:MyGenericRecord a="Max" b="7500" />
    <local:MyGenericRecord a="Average" b="5000" />
</DataGrid>
```

Converter:

```
public class WidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        double totalWidth = 0;

        foreach (double Width in values)
            totalWidth += Width;
        DataGridLength outLen = new DataGridLength(totalWidth);
        return outLen;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue};
    }
}

public class MyGenericRecord
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check type of items in values array in converter. Most likely some of them are DependencyProperty.UnsetValue and not double. To test - change to foreach (double width in values.OfType<double>()).

Comment: I second the check for `UnsetValue`. It's the most unexpected thing to come across the first time. Could also be caused by your `ConvertBack`. If you aren't actually using it to convert back, it's usually best to leave it throwing a NotSupportedException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any converter you should always expect value (or values) can be `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`. This value is used by wpf when actual value cannot be obtained for whatever reason. Most often it happens when binding cannot be resolved (for example - you bind to property which does not exist). WPF designer does not compile the whole code, so it might misbehave, especially with bindings. Note that `null` could not be used instead of `UnsetValue`, because `null` can be a valid value. So expect `UnsetValue` and if possible, try to do something meaningful in that case. For example:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    double totalWidth = 0;
    foreach (double Width in values.OfType<double>())
        totalWidth += Width;
    DataGridLength outLen = new DataGridLength(totalWidth);
    return outLen;
}
```

This will ignore all values which are not double (including `UnsetValue`).